# Log Callout Exception - Uncommitted work pending workaround

Tags: apex, callout, exception, logging

I want to perform 5 callouts and log any callout exceptions as a new case. Since mixing callouts and DMLs is not allowed, I made the logging asynchronous. Unfortunately, an ExecutionException ("uncommitted work pending") is still being thrown when the new case is inserted into the DB by the @future method. Here's the callout class (simplified):

```
class CalloutClass {
    // ...
    public CustomResponse doCallout() {
        try {
            // ... callout logic
        } catch (CalloutException coe) {
            LogUtil.logException(coe.getTypeName());    // @future method
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a List of Cases that you want to insert once all the callouts are complete. Each time time you catch a CalloutException add the new case to this list.

Once you have completed (or attempted) all your callouts insert the list of cases.

```
class CalloutClass {

    private List<Case> CalloutExceptions { get; set; }

    public CalloutClass() {
        this.CalloutExceptions = new List<Case>();
    }       

    public CustomResponse doCallout() {
        try {
            // ... callout logic
        } catch (CalloutException coe) {
            // No longer future. Just returns the Case to insert.
            Case caseToInsert = LogUtil.logException(coe.getTypeName());    
            this.CalloutExceptions.add(caseToInsert);
        }
    }

    public void logCalloutCases() {
        if(this.CalloutExceptions.size() > 0) {
            insert this.CalloutExceptions;
        }
    }
}

CalloutClass cc = new CalloutClass();
cc.doCallout();
//... Make the remainder of the callouts.
cc.logCalloutCases();
```